# Importing a large text file into Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a pipe delimited text file that is 360GB, compressed (gzip). The file is in an S3 bucket. 
This is my first time using Spark. I understand that you can partition a file in order to allow multiple worker nodes to operate on the data which results in huge performance gains. However, I'm trying to find an efficient way to turn my one 360GB file into a partitioned file. Is there a way to use multiple spark worker nodes to work on my one, compressed file in order to partition it? Unfortunately, I have no control over the fact that I'm just getting one huge file. I could uncompress the file myself and break it into many files (say 360 1GB files), but I'll just be using one machine to do that and it will be pretty slow. I need to run some expensive transformations on the data using Spark so I think partitioning the file is necessary. I'm using Spark inside of Amazon Glue so I know that it can scale to a large number of machines. Also, I'm using python (pyspark).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already know how would you like to partition it? Do you have a good partitioning candidate already (column(s))? How do you want to process this data in future?

Comment: Yes, the data has DMA. There are 210 DMAs. It's not perfect because some DMAs will have more data than others, but I think it's my best option. My question, though,is how to deal efficiently with this single 360GB file.

Comment: But isn't this CSV file already partitioned? How has it been written/saved?

Comment: No, the file I'm importing is not partitioned. It's a single, gzipped 360GB pipe delimited file.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with S3 storage. Is it possible to partiion it anyhow using S3 methods? I don't think you can benefit from using Spark unless this file is partitioned anyhow, so that you cann process it using multiple workers. As soon as it's partitioned - you can repartition it by `DMA` column

Comment: I don't think S3 can do this - it's just storage. Can I get Spark to partition the file for me or do I have to do that myself? It sounds like, if Spark can partition the file, it will have to use a single node.

Comment: What about using [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)? I'm not sure whether it will be faster/more efficient compared to processing it in Spark using one worker... PS I don't know whether Spark is able to process a single unpartitioned file using multiple workers - I don't understand who, how and by which rules would split this file for us in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157410/discussion-between-dwayne-driskill-and-maxu).

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken, Spark uses Hadoop's `TextInputFormat` if you read a file using `SparkContext.textFile`. If a compression codec is set, the `TextInputFormat` determines if the file is splittable by checking if the code is an instance of `SplittableCompressionCodec`.

I believe GZIP is not splittable, Spark can only generate one partition to read the entire file.

What you could do is: 
1. Add a repartition after `SparkContext.textFile` so you at least have more than one of your transformations process parts of the data.
2. Ask for multiple files instead of just a single GZIP file 
3. Write an application that decompresses and splits the files into multiple output files before running your Spark application on it. 
4. Write your own compression codec for GZIP (this is a little more complex).

Have a look at these links:

`TextInputFormat`
[source code for TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) 
`GzipCodec`
[source code for GZIPCodec](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/GzipCodec.html)

These are in java, but i'm sure there are equivalent Python/Scala versions of them.

Comment: You could also change the type of compression used to one that's splittable, like BZip2

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest you have to used ORC format with zlib compression so you get almost 70% compression and as per my research ORC is the most suitable file format for fastest data processing. So you have to load your file and simply write it into orc format with repartition.

```
df.repartition(500).write.option("compression","zlib").mode("overwrite").save("testoutput.parquet")
```

Comment: you can change the repartition value as per your data size.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution could be to use [Amazon's S3DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) as a step on your EMR cluster to copy the 360GB file in the HDFS file system available on the cluster (this requires Hadoop to be deployed on the EMR).

A nice thing about S3DistCp is that you can change the codec of the output file, and transform the original gzip file into a format which will allow Spark to spawn multiple partitions for its RDD.

However I am not sure about how long it will take for S3DistCp to perform the operation (which is an Hadoop Map/Reduce over S3. It benefits from optimised S3 libraries when run from an EMR, but I am concerned that Hadoop will face the same limitations as Spark when generating the Map tasks).